# Ownership question about Ethereum ERC20 tokens

Tags: erc-20, transfer

I been considering creating my own Ethereum ERC20 token and I have one main question. When you create a Ethereum ERC20 token and you launch it, do you automatically own all of that Ethereum ERC20 tokens that are not being traded or being held, or do you have to transfer a certain portion of those Ethereum ERC-20 tokens to a certain account for the ownership?

Following that question, are you allowed to sell your own Ethereum ERC20 token?
Thank you to anyone who can answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two ways how to create supply of your ERC20 token.

1. you can create all tokens at the moment of deployment, in that case all tokens belongs to you as the deployer and the total supply is immutable
2. you can have your ERC20 token mintable and have another contract that would mint and distribute it somehow (you can sell it for ETH for example)